# Why adding a return type to a void returning method causes a MissingMethodException

Tags: c#, .net, clr

I have a .NET application that uses an assembly (.dll) that defines some method:

```
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        // Do work
    }
```

Suppose this method signature changes to include a *string* return type:

```
    public string DoSomething()
    {
        // Do work
        return "something";
    }
```

Why does the code that uses this method fails on a *System.MissingMethodException* ?

It seems to me, that at all call sites to this method, no use was made of the return value (since it did not exist before).

Why does this change break the code then?

Comment: Edited my example. My point was that the method returns something now; but all code that previously used it do not do anything with it. It is perfectly legal to write such code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you did a breaking api change. You did either change the method signature in a base class or an interface.

The callers are linked against this method. In IL a method reference is not only a reference to a type and its method with some index to the method but the callers method references does include the complete method signature.

This change is therefore fixable by a recompile of all assemblies that call this method but you get run time exceptions when you only recompile the changed assembly and hope the the using assemblies will magically pick up the changed method signature. This is not the case because the method reference does contain the complete method signature and defining type.

It did happen to me also. You are right that nobody could use the return type so this change is safe but you need to recompile all affected targets.

Comment: Thanks. I was under the impression that only the method name + parameter types were used for inferring which method to call.

Comment: it is actually typeref + methodref where the method reference does contain name, return type, type arguemtns, generic arguments and calling convention

Comment: @liortal: The return type is not used by C# in determining which method to call. But C# definitely needs to know the return type *to generate correct code in the caller of the method*.

Answer (score 16):

The other answers which state that you've changed the signature of a method, and therefore must recompile the callers, are correct. I thought I might add some additional information about this bit of your question:

> It seems to me, that at all call sites to this method, no use was made of the return value (since it did not exist before).

That is exactly right. Now, consider this question: how do you write code that *makes no use of data*? You seem to be labouring under the entirely false assumption that *not using a value* requires no code, but not using a value certainly does require code!

Suppose you have methods:

```
static int M1(int y) { return y + 1; }
static void M2(int z) { ... }
```

and you have a call

```
int x;
x = M1(123);
```

What happens *at the IL level*? the following:

- Allocate space on the temporary pool for x.
- Push 123 on the stack
- Invoke M1.
- Push 1 on the stack. Stack is now 1, 123
- Add the top two things on the stack. This pops both and pushes the result. Stack is now 124.
- Return to the caller
- The stack is still 124.
- Store the value on the stack into the temporary storage for x. This pops the stack, so the stack is now empty.

Suppose you now do:

```
M1(345);
```

What happens?  *Same thing*:

- Push 345 on the stack
- Invoke M1.
- Push 1 on the stack. Stack is now 1, 345
- Add the top two things on the stack. This pops both and pushes the result. Stack is now 346.
- Return to the caller
- The stack is still 346.

But there is no instruction which stores the value on the stack anywhere, so we have to issue a pop instruction:

- Pop the unused value off the stack.

Now suppose you call

```
M2(456);
```

What happens?

- Push 456 on the stack
- Invoke M2.
- M2 does its thing. When it returns to the caller, the stack is empty because it is void returning.
- The stack is now empty, so do not pop anything off it.

Now do you see why changing a method from void returning to value returning is a breaking change?  **Every caller now has to pop the unused value off the stack**. Doing *nothing* with data *still requires cleaning it up off the stack*. You are misaligning the stack if you do not pop that value off; the CLR requires the stack to be *empty* at the beginning of every statement to ensure that this sort of misalignment does not happen.

Comment: +100 Achievement Unlocked -- (Eric Lippert answered your question)

Comment: A balanced stack is a good thing. But sometimes I really would like to copy some values from the stack of my caller especially the method handle to get a very cheap stack walk of my caller. At IL level I have not found any way to do this. Are you aware of such a possibility or do I have to resort back to GetStackFramesInternal?

Comment: @AloisKraus the IL evaluation stack is not the same thing as the call stack.  The evaluation stack is rather more virtual.  See Eric's answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/7877736/385844 for more details.

Comment: Nice link. That is really good stuff. But I hoped that some "under documented" IL opcode could let me reach the thread stack in a cheap albeit not safe manner.

Answer (score 2):

If there's no reflection involved but the linking is static (I assume this from the description) then the runtime will try to find a method using the exact signature. It's just how CIL's `callvirt` works.

It doesn't matter then whether or not the value is consumed - the runtime is unable to locate the `void YourClass::DoSomething()` and it doesn't even try to look for `string YourClass::DoSomething()`.

If such change was possible then you could easily blow up the runtime by causing stack underflows/overflows.

Comment: +1 Not to mention that you wouldn't want it guessing and perhaps picking the wrong method - which could get nasty fast...

Comment: I thought that picking the method was done only by looking at its name + parameters.

Comment: @liortal For C#, method signature (used for handling method overloads) does not include return type.  In the CLR, method signature does include return type.  Presumably that means it's possible to write a language allowing overloads `int M()` and `string M()` in the same class.  C# isn't that language.  For more details, see Eric Lippert's post on the subject: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8521944/385844

Answer (score 1):

Because you've changed the method signature.

When the external code needs to locate a method, it needs to ensure what it is calling is correct. It stores some of this information as a signature at compile time - the signature information includes the return type (regardless of whether it is actually used anywhere).

As far as the CLR is concerned, a method with a void return type no longer exists - hence the `MissingMethodException`.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder what the MSIL of that looks like (before and after).

Answer (score 0):

The makers of C# decided it should be strict about method signatures.

Comment: From the exception (`MissingMethodException`) I belive he's describing a runtime error caused by replacing the dll with another one. If this is so then it has nothing to do with C#.